# Description of a set in the Baire space.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, the-baire-space

I have the following exercise.

In the Baire space, $\omega ^ \omega$ ,describe a set $A$ such that $int(A)\neq \emptyset$ and $A\neq \bar{A}$

I recently just got to know the Baire space, it is difficult for me to understand it a bit and I have come across this exercise. Could you please help me with an example. Thank you.

Edit:

I have considered the following set: $A=\{ x\in \omega ^ \omega: x\nleq f\}$ And I have shown that it is open. But I have the doubt, that for example in the discrete metric all open is closed at the same time, and I cannot see how to show that this set is not closed

Comment: I'm a bit naive about Baire space. Why can't you take any open set that is not closed? If it's open, then it's equal to its interior. If it's not closed, it's not equal to its closure.

Comment: @TSF Yes, basically the problem consists in giving an open, but that is my problem, giving a particular open, so I say that it is difficult for me to see such an example.

Comment: Can you think of a set that is closed but not open? Then its complement will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Consider the point $f$ itself: clearly $f\notin A$, but you should be able to show that $f\in\operatorname{cl}A$. It may help to prove that the sets $$B_n=\{x\in\omega^\omega:x(k)=f(k)\text{ for all }k\le n\}$$ for $n\in\omega$ are a local base at $f$, if you don’t already know this fact.